# ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating the game when the player hits the enemy, the health bar should -1 out of 3. When I click play, the game is working, but the error of ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: layer2 is out of range. Layer numbers must be in the range 0 to 31 still persists. Can anyone help me please.

Here is the code:

```
public class PlayerControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject heart1, heart2, heart3;
    public int playerHealth = 3;
    int playerLayer, enemyLayer;
    bool coroutineAllowed = true;
    Color color;
    Renderer rend;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        playerLayer = this.gameObject.layer;
        enemyLayer = LayerMask.NameToLayer("Enemy");
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(playerLayer, enemyLayer, false);
        heart1 = GameObject.Find("heart1");
        heart2 = GameObject.Find("heart2");
        heart3 = GameObject.Find("heart3");
        heart1.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        heart2.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        heart3.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
        color = rend.material.color;
    }

    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D col)
    {
        if (col.gameObject.tag.Equals("Enemy"))
        {
            playerHealth -= 1;
            switch (playerHealth)
            {
                case 2:
                    heart3.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    if (coroutineAllowed)
                        StartCoroutine("Immortal");
                    break;

                case 1:
                    heart2.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    if (coroutineAllowed)
                        StartCoroutine("Immortal");
                    break;

                case 0:
                    heart1.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                    if (coroutineAllowed) StartCoroutine("Immortal");
                    break;
            }
        }

        if (playerHealth < 1)
        {
            gameOverText.SetActive(true);
            restartButton.SetActive(true);
            restartBox.SetActive(true);
            Instantiate(blood, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Immortal()
    {
        coroutineAllowed = false;
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(playerLayer, enemyLayer, true);
        color.a = 0.5f;
        rend.material.color = color;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
        Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision(playerLayer, enemyLayer, false);
        color.a = 1f;
        rend.material.color = color;
        coroutineAllowed = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line does the exception happen?

Comment: Hi, it show as attached, everything works fine. I don't know why.
[link] (https://www.linkpicture.com/view.php?img=LPic6080054718f15547900204)

Comment: As for now I just fixed the error of AnimationEvent has no function name specified. But I still get the **_ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: layer2 is out of range. Layer numbers must be in the range 0 to 31._**

Comment: Please use the correct tags. Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code rather looks like `c#`. Also just because you are using a certain IDE (`visual studio`) doesn't mean that your question is actually about that IDE.

Answer (score 0):

From [`LayerMask.NameToLayer`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/LayerMask.NameToLayer.html)

> Given a layer name, returns the layer index as defined by either a Builtin or a User Layer in the [Tags and Layers manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TagManager.html).
>
> **Returns -1 if not found.**

Sounds like you do not have configured any layer called `Enemy` so `enemyLayer` will have the value `-1` which is not an allowed parameter for `Physics2D.IgnoreLayerCollision`.